# index std/boost::map by struct element

Tags: c++, dictionary, struct, indexing, element

I have found this [excellent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905716/cannot-use-a-struct-as-index-of-a-map) that's a slight reverse of what I want to do.

I'm still too noob to really understand what's going on.  (I'm just now barely getting comfortable with barely more than the basic syntax)

What I want to do is index a `std::map` of `struct`s by one of the `struct`'s elements.

So, if I have

```
struct accountStruct{
     string accountName;
     double total;
};
```

I'd like to call the `total` from `std/boost::map` of `accountStruct`s with `accounts[accountName].total`.

Please show me how.

Comment: For an easy insertion, you could use a `std::set` instead of a `std::map` by defining a `bool operator<(accountStruct const&, accountStruct const&)`. However, `std::set` has no `operator[]`, and the equivalent `std::set::find` member function requires a complete object of the `value_type` (here: `accountStruct` and not `string`) until we get C++14. An ugly workaround would be to create a dummy object for find, e.g. `my_set.find({"needle", 0});` (possibly as a static local variable of a wrapper function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `std::map<std::string, accountStruct>`. However, this wouldn't automatically fill in the `accountName` in your `accountStruct` when you insert elements into your map. The `std::map<K, V>` certainly don't consider using a field of a user provided `struct` as a key. You may want to use a `std::map<std::string, double>` directly, though. ... or leave the account name out of the `accountStruct`:

```
struct accountStruct {
    double total = 0.0;
    // possibly other members
};

std::map<std::string, accountStruct> m;
```

Comment: Thank you!  Didn't think of the obvious: let `accountName` stand on its own as key only.